# JMeter | Text to QR Code and back to text

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

1. I have an API that generates Base64 text that can be converted to a QR code. Using https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image (or any other similar tool).
2. Once it is generated we are getting a QR code.
3. using the phone or https://4qrcode.com/scan-qr-code.php we can decrypt the QR code back to text so I can use this text for the next API.
4. Example of the text to be converted to QR:
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/hiz3mckw1ynqxn4/QR-CodeSnippet.txt?dl=0
5. Here is the text example from QR:

- 0$cUYpeMdDiAHe&z+-o7C1ljDr8N<Hr=gG8pfqHni8sAUpGyUpA+,EbpH=M7vK[NfifD}kQ?Did8K5zBkr5jSd9s5>iw]wj&t$lE+::W[}1{asu@6UMNdRwu1F]2dmj,cMJ/FlQAlaHXe-u/VBk4&xY>dVVD7)ZeO@QMvi)uv

I was advised  to use the libraries below but I'm not sure where to start, so I would appreciate any explanations
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/3.4.1

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core/1.4.0

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase/3.4.1

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander/1.78

Answer (score 0):

1. Take all the jar files and drop them to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick them up
3. Add a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and use the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) there:

   ```
   def text  = new File('c:/temp/QR-CodeSnippet.txt').text
   def image = text.substring(text.indexOf(',') + 1)


   byte[] imageBytes = image.decodeBase64()

   def bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes)
   def bufferedImage = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(bis)

   def imageSource = new com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage)

   def binarizer = new com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer(imageSource)
   def bitmap = new com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap(binarizer)
   def multiFormatReader = new com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader()

   def result = multiFormatReader.decode(bitmap)
   def content = result.getText()

   log.info('Content from the QR code: ' + content)
   ```
4. .....
5. Profit?

[image]